# SQLite-net Table<>() method call performance

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, sqlite, xamarin

I am using SQLite-net library with **Xamarin** and I have a question.
Which call is better or faster?

```
var item = sQLiteConnection.Table<User>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == myobject.Id);
```

Or

```
var item = sQLiteConnection.Table<User>().Where(e => e.Id == myobject.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Why don't you profile it to see if there are any performance differences?

Comment: The first one is the one to be used, only because you can write less code to do the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either is fine.

They both run lazily - if the source list has a million items, but the tenth item matches then both will only iterate 10 items from the source.

Performance should be almost identical and any difference would be totally insignificant.

but

I started getting "The wait operation timed out." using `Where(query).FirstOrDefault()` on a large dataset. When I changed it to `FirstOrDefault(query)` I stopped seeing it

The difference I get when I compare the two approaches is working out to be 1ms for over 150,000 items (not 1ms for each item, it's 1ms for all 150,000). So based on that your 500 x 1,000 items query that's about 0.003ms per day. It's not significant

but I personally prefer  FirstOrDefault(query)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use

```
var item = sQLiteConnection.Table<User>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == myobject.Id)
```

> It return the first element of matching condition.

But

```
var item = sQLiteConnection.Table<User>().Where(e => e.Id == myobject.Id);
```

This will bring you a collection of data that matches your condition.
so until it iterate your end of your collection it will do this.

Using`Where(e => e.Id == myobject.Id).FirstOrDefault();` after the where your fetch first element after the iteration. This is additional overhead.

Considering the readability always be less verbose.

See [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx) vs [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx)